# Unable to clone git repository on ubuntu

Tags: ubuntu, git

While cloning git repository I am getting the following error 

Failed to connect to github.com port 443:Network is ureachable while I am able to clone on my windows machine

 Edited-

```
 git clone https://github.com/Rishav09/Mywebsite.git
```

I am getting the following error

```
Cloning into 'Mywebsite'...
fatal: unable to access 'https://github.com/Rishav09/Mywebsite.git/':
Failed to connect to github.com port 443: Network is unreachable
```

Comment: I doubt its git problem, but more related to firewall issues. What's the repository you're trying to clone ?

Comment: Please add the corresponding git command to the post.

Comment: Works perfectly fine for me. Just cloned  the repository. I'm on Ubuntu as well. Definitely you have some network problems, not related to `git`

Comment: okay,I checked other similar problems but they were for windows ,they were insisting on using a proxy

Comment: @Serg I am not on secure server,its not https ,does this have any problem in cloning

Comment: https does not have any relation to this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Is there a firewall/proxy in place restriciting access?

Can you clone via SSH (note: you'll need a GitHub account and need to add your public SSH key to your profile to be able to SSH in).

```
git clone ssh://git@github.com/Rishav09/Mywebsite.git
```

Comment: Thanks it worked ,could you tell why I was unable to clone via https and No,there is no firewall/proxy

Comment: If there is nothing restricting access, then see Ezwig's response below as to the most likely cause (DNS issue).

Comment: I have tried the same but i got  the error 'Cloning into 'data_model'...
ssh: Could not resolve hostname github.com:M-Thirumal: Name or service not known
fatal: Could not read from remote repository.'